# Why PHP FPM pm-dynamic has such massive overhead?

Tags: php, nginx, fpm

I have a very fast Drupal website (backend response 8ms with Memcached).

End user responses (via Google Page Speed) range from 160ms to 620ms when `pm dynamic` is set as FPM governor.

Switching to `pm-static` and every response is exactly 150ms.

Why `pm dynamic` has so much overhead in terms of starting new children processes?

Comment: How many times did you try? In dynamic mode, the server may start new processes, so that would be slower the first time the process is started, then it may respond more quickly. Please share the configuration.

Comment: Thanks mate - after few more weeks of benchmarking and trial & error. I have been able to achieve a reasonable solution with 1) increasing start up servers and 2) reducing max requests. I have aimed for 90% of traffic finding an active process.

Comment: feel free to add it in an answer, it may help other people.